# Can't set cookies from the server in a production environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, cookies, jwt

I deployed my NodeJS server to [Railway](https://railway.app/) and my ReactJS app to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/).

In the sign in process after I authenticate the user I want to set a cookie in the client from the server with a token that represents the user.

Now in the **development environment** when I perform the sign in process the browser recieves the cookie properly and the sign in process goes well.

Unlike the **production environment** when I perform the sign in process no cookies were set in the client.

---

In the `CookieOptions` object

I tried to set the `domain` property to `.railway.app` but it didn't work.

Then I tried to set the `sameSite` property to `lax` but it didn't work as well.

Finally I tried to set the `secure` proprty to `true` but it didn't work.

And this is how I set the cookie from the server

```
    const token: string = createToken(user.id);
    const options: CookieOptions = { path: '/', domain: process.env.COOKIES_DOMAIN, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2, secure: true, sameSite: "lax" };
    res.status(201).cookie('token', token, options).json({ succeed: true, response: "Sign in succeed" });
```

Comment: Are you using HTTP o HTTPS?

Comment: I am using HTTPS. I guess it is the default protocol on both Railway and Vercel.